# Regex find time values

Tags: regex, time, format, grep

I keep getting into situations where I end up making two regular expressions to find subtle changes (such as one script for 0-9 and another for 10-99 because of the extra number)

I usually use `[0-9]` to find strings with just one digit and then `[0-9][0-9]` to find strings with multiple digits, is there a better wildcard for this?

ex. what expression would I use to simultaneously find the strings
    `6:45 AM and 10:52 PM`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can specify repetition with curly braces. `[0-9]{2,5}` matches two to five digits. So you could use `[0-9]{1,2}` to match one or two.

`[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} (AM|PM)`

I personally prefer to use `\d` for digits, thus

`\d{1,2}:\d{2} (AM|PM)`

Answer (score 2):

`[0-9]` 1 or 2 times followed by `:` followed by 2 `[0-9]`:

```
[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}\s(AM|PM)
```

or to be valid time:

```
(?:[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-9]{2}\s(?:AM|PM)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a time patten, you'd do something like:

```
\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} (AM|PM)
```

Or for more specific time regex

```
[0-1]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2}:[0-5][0-9] (AM|PM)
```

Answer (score 1):

Much like the other answers, except the AM/PM is not captured, which should be more efficient

```
\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s(?:AM|PM)
```

Answer (score 0):

if I have a file containing:

> 1 ABC
>   2 123XYZ
>   3 6:45 AM
>   4 123DHD
>   5 ABC
>   6 10:52 PM
>   7 CDE

and run the following

```
$>grep -P '6:45\sAM|10:52\sPM' temp
6:45 AM
10:52 PM
$>.
```

should do the trick (-P is a perl regx)

**EDIT:**

Perhaps I misunderstood, the other answers are very good if I were looking to just find a time, but you seem to be after specific times. the others would match ANY time in HH:MM format.

overall, I believe the items you are after would be the | pipe character which is used in this case to allow alternative phrases and the {n,m} match n-m times {1,2} would match 1-2 times, etc.

Comment: hey, I wasn't after specific times, I gave those two examples to illustrate the most extreme differences in the values I needed to find. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: no problem. I'm glad you found an appropriate answer so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It can be able to check all type of time formats :

e.g. `12:05PM, 3:19AM, 04:25PM, 23:52PM`

```
my $time = "12:52AM";
if ($time =~ /^[01]?[0-9]\:[0-5][0-9](AM|PM)/) {
    print "Right Time Dude...";
}
else { print "Wrong time Dude"; }
```

This is the regex you want.

```
    /^[01]?[0-9]\:[0-5][0-9](AM|PM)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Having this string as input:

```
Sat, 6 May 2017 02:08:08 +0000
```

I did this regEx to get combinations of one or two digits:

```
[0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*
```